# Azure Data Factory using CopyActivity does not use bulk update lock (BU)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm performing a test by using the copy activity where the source is a 2GB file with about 10 million rows going into an empty table with no indexes.  When I look at the locks on this table using the query below while the activity is running, I only see a lock type of "X" request_mode (exclusive).  Shouldn't I see a lock type of "BU"?  I do see that the recovery model of the database is "FULL".  Should this be set to "Bulk-Logged"?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
  WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID()
  AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.EmptyTestTable');
```